# Python - Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-21ft0H/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, centos7

I'm using Centos 7 and Python 2.7.5. The problem is when I install Pandas, i got this error message

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-21ft0H/pandas
```

I already tried a lot of solutions but no success even `yum -y update`.

- [Can't install via pip because of egg_info error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error)
- [Python pip install fails: invalid command egg_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info)
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4
- [pip fails to install anything, error: invalid command 'egg_info'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719816/pip-fails-to-install-anything-error-invalid-command-egg-info)

Comment: Are you in a virtualenv? It looks like you're installing using `pip install pandas`, is this correct? What do you get when running `pip -V` and `python -V` inside and outside of the virtualenv (if applies)?

Comment: yes if not mistaken. I'm using Digital Ocean BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found the answer. I need to install python via RPM.

```
rpm -i ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/7.1.1503/updates/x86_64/Packages/python-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2015/11/14/python-command-python-setup-py-egg_info-failed-with-error-code-1-tmppip-build-21ft0hpandas/

Comment: What about `yum install python-matplotlib` for me it worked!

Comment: @SIslam your comment helped me when nothing else did. Thank you!

Comment: @SIslam your comment is the actual answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Distribute has been merged into Setuptools as of version 0.7. If you are using a version <=0.6, upgrade using `pip install --upgrade setuptools` or `easy_install -U setuptools`.

Comment: You should reference your answer if it is not your own answer! This answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info

Answer (score 1):

In my case for continuos integration work:

```
before_script:
  - apk update && apk add python3-dev
  - apk add --no-cache python3-dev libstdc++
  - apk add --update curl gcc g++
  - ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h
  - pip3 install numpy
  - pip3 install pandas
  - rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
  - python -V
  - python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  - python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel --user --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install -- upgrade pip python -m pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

following link solved my problem

https://googleapis/google-cloud-python#3884

You should try pip install --upgrade setuptools.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

i used this when i got similar error during matplotlib install

Answer (score 0):

simply execute this command :

sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while installing mysqlclient from pip3

So I executed command :

`sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev`

After executing this command i was able to install mysqlclient successfully

Note:- Version Number 3.6 is to be replaced by your python version