# Spyder fails to install spc 0.3 caused by a "python setup.py egg_info"

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I am trying to install SPC at a Win 64-bit platform through Spyder Anaconda. After trying the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719816/pip-fails-to-install-anything-error-invalid-command-egg-info), I run ez_setup but still getting the following error:

```
pip install spc
Collecting spc
 Using cached spc-0.3.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "c:\users\....\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-gfpds4\spc\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
from ez_setup import use_setuptools
ImportError: No module named ez_setup

----------------------------------------
 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-gfpds4\spc\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try installing `ez_setup` from pip first:

```
pip install ez_setup
```

and then install spc:

```
pip install spc
```

I believe the authors forgot to add `ez_setup` as an installation requirement in the `setup.py`, like they did for `numpy`:

```
 % sudo pip install ez_setup
Collecting ez-setup
  Downloading ez_setup-0.9.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: ez-setup
  Running setup.py install for ez-setup ... done
Successfully installed ez-setup-0.9
 % sudo pip install spc
Collecting spc
  Using cached spc-0.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): NumPy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from spc)
Installing collected packages: spc
  Running setup.py install for spc ... done
Successfully installed spc-0.3
```

Comment: You are right! After installing ez_setup the problem has solved. Thanks!

Comment: no pb, you're welcome! If I did help you, please accept and up vote my answer ;-)

Comment: Of course. You can add your answer as a comment to the original question that I mention above.

Comment: their issue is actually non related to your issue