# Pip won't let me install any packages

Tags: python, pip

I am extremely new to python, the answer is probably sitting in front of my face, but I just can't seem to find it. Pip won't let me install any packages. I'm using pip version 20.2.4, and python version 3.9.0. I'm on windows 10.

```
C:\Users\Scott Evans>pip install pandas

    Collecting pandas
      Downloading pandas-1.1.3.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 5.2 MB 6.8 MB/s
      Installing build dependencies ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pgp9djhn\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
           cwd: None
      Complete output (590 lines):
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
      Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21
        Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.17.3
        Downloading numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Scott Evans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-41rf5zel\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Scott Evans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-41rf5zel\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-_cxurpcg'
             cwd: C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-41rf5zel\numpy\
        Complete output (268 lines):
        Running from numpy source directory.
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        blis_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        openblas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
        customize GnuFCompiler
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable f77
        customize IntelVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable ifort
        Could not locate executable ifl
        customize AbsoftFCompiler
        Could not locate executable f90
        customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable DF
        customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efl
        customize Gnu95FCompiler
        Could not locate executable gfortran
        Could not locate executable f95
        customize G95FCompiler
        Could not locate executable g95
        customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
        customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efort
        Could not locate executable efc
        customize PGroupFlangCompiler
        Could not locate executable flang
        don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        atlas_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        atlas_blas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        accelerate_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-41rf5zel\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
            Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
            Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
            A better performance should be easily gained by switching
            Blas library.
          self.calc_info()
        blas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-41rf5zel\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
            the BLAS environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
        blas_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-41rf5zel\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
            the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        openblas_lapack_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
       
    

C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-41rf5zel\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
            the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
          warnings.warn(msg)
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running config_cc
        unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
        running config_fc
        unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
        running build_src
        build_src
        building py_modules sources
        creating build
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
        building library "npymath" sources
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
        ----------------------------------------
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
        Running setup.py clean for numpy
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Scott Evans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-41rf5zel\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Scott Evans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-41rf5zel\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
             cwd: C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-41rf5zel\numpy
        Complete output (10 lines):
        Running from numpy source directory.
    
        `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
    
          - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
          - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                              files that aren't checked into the git repo)
    
        Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
    
        ----------------------------------------
        ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
      Failed to build numpy
      Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, numpy
          Running setup.py install for numpy: started
          Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
           command: 'c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Scott Evans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-41rf5zel\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Scott Evans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-41rf5zel\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xyc0gk8l\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pgp9djhn\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pgp9djhn\overlay\Include\numpy'
               cwd: C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-41rf5zel\numpy\
          Complete output (273 lines):
          Running from numpy source directory.
    
          Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
          with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
    
            - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                     release)
            - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)
    
    
          blas_opt_info:
          blas_mkl_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          blis_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          openblas_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils`enter code here`
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
          customize GnuFCompiler
          Could not locate executable g77
          Could not locate executable f77
          customize IntelVisualFCompiler
          Could not locate executable ifort
          Could not locate executable ifl
          customize AbsoftFCompiler
          Could not locate executable f90
          customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
          Could not locate executable DF
          customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
          Could not locate executable efl
          customize Gnu95FCompiler
          Could not locate executable gfortran
          Could not locate executable f95
          customize G95FCompiler
          Could not locate executable g95
          customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
          customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
          Could not locate executable efort
          Could not locate executable efc
          customize PGroupFlangCompiler
          Could not locate executable flang
          don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_blas_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_blas_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_blas_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          accelerate_info:
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-41rf5zel\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
              Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
              Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
              A better performance should be easily gained by switching
              Blas library.
            self.calc_info()
          blas_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-41rf5zel\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
              Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
              Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
              the BLAS environment variable.
            self.calc_info()
          blas_src_info:
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\Scott Evans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-41rf5zel\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
              Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
              Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
              the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
            self.calc_info()
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
          operable program or batch file.
          non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
          lapack_opt_info:
          lapack_mkl_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          openblas_lapack_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          openblas_clapack_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          flame_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\scott evans\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_info:
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
          No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\scott evans\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pip install ends with "command errored out with exit status 1:..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413061/python-pip-install-ends-with-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1)

Comment: This is an issue with Python 3.9 and the pandas dependencies not being updated yet.  If you want to get started now, downgrade to 3.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have issues with the wheels, and that is because not all offical wheels are out yet for Python 3.9, the following command installs the unoffical wheels.

Type the following command

```
pip install pipwin
```

then

```
pipwin install pandas
```