# I'm getting this error while trying to install d3dshot using pip

Tags: python

```py
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k0wc55ke\\pillow_e48debd8a95e4117be74fbd34b18496b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k0wc55ke\\pillow_e48debd8a95e4117be74fbd34b18496b\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9tt4zm7s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pillow'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k0wc55ke\pillow_e48debd8a95e4117be74fbd34b18496b\
    Complete output (177 lines):
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k0wc55ke\pillow_e48debd8a95e4117be74fbd34b18496b\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.1.2 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    adding license file 'LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k0wc55ke\pillow_e48debd8a95e4117be74fbd34b18496b\setup.py", line 860, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k0wc55ke\pillow_e48debd8a95e4117be74fbd34b18496b\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k0wc55ke\pillow_e48debd8a95e4117be74fbd34b18496b\setup.py", line 914, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of pillow
  Moving to c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pil\
   from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~il
  Moving to c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pillow-8.3.1.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~illow-8.3.1.dist-info
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k0wc55ke\\pillow_e48debd8a95e4117be74fbd34b18496b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k0wc55ke\\pillow_e48debd8a95e4117be74fbd34b18496b\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9tt4zm7s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pillow' Check the logs for full command output
```

Comment: are you using mac?

Comment: No, I'm on windows 10

Comment: what did you type in cmd? ```pip install d3dshot``` ?

Comment: Yeah, but i'm getting that error when trying to install it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pip install ends with "command errored out with exit status 1:..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413061/python-pip-install-ends-with-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1)

Comment: There should be more backtrace than just this error. Include the rest of the relevant output.

Comment: Also include the Python version in your question.

Comment: The whole error code has been included.

Comment: I'm using the latest py version

Comment: "I'm using the latest py version": what is `py`, and what version? "Latest" is a generic term.

Comment: "The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.": this is your problem. Pillow is being compiled from source, but you don't have the relevant files available. The reason for it being compiled from source is probably because relevant binary files don't yet exist; see also the duplicate suggestion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That's the whole error code, anyways, I tried some of the linked topics but it doesn't seem to work, still getting the same error. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Note: This is only when i use the "pip install d3dshot", however, when I try to install other packages, I do not get any errors.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you are still looking into this, I ran into this issue and fixed by downloading the source code from https://github.com/SerpentAI/D3DShot opening pyproject.toml and replacing:

```
pillow = "~7.1.2"
```

with

```
pillow = ">=7.1.2"
```

install with:

```
$ pip install ./D3DShot-dev
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! I had to reinstall `matplotlib` because of the PIL module not found error. Thank you!

Comment: pip install ./D3DShot-dev didn't work for me, saying "ERROR: Invalid requirement: './D3DShot-dev'", so what I did was install "build" using pip, run "py -m build" in the folder with the toml file, then insall the .whl file directly via its path using "pip install file path here"

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade to Python 3.8.  Then the pip install of it worked fine.