# Why does "from PIL import Image" not work, but "from pil import Image" does? (lowercase pil)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, modulenotfounderror

I've come across this strange error with Pillow, where the import name `PIL` needs to be all lowercase instead of all uppercase, but I've never seen `pil` used lowercase anywhere. This means that all the python packages and files that I use that import `PIL` don't work and throw a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`. However when change "PIL" to "pil", the import works.

Pillow version = 9.0.0
Python version = 3.9.1

I came across this error after trying to install d3dshot package. Installing d3dshot using pip threw an error about a missing zlib dependency for Pillow, and I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68942856/im-getting-this-error-while-trying-to-install-d3dshot-using-pip/70702503#70702503?newreg=968ec66a7b2546d1a5ba4be95ece0dd4) to successfully install d3dshot. After that, I started encountering this PIL error.

Comment: If I remember right, pil went through a weird update and changed the capitalization at some point. Old tutorials will probably use the old capitalization. Don't have enough time to make this a full answer right now

Comment: interesting, i installed pil 9.0.0 just now and can only use `import PIL`, not `import pil`

Comment: @ProQ where did you get that information? Pillow is still imported via `PIL`

Comment: The Pillow version of the PIL has used uppercase `PIL` for as long as I can remember (i.e. since its beginning) — probably for historical reasons as it's always shrived to be compatible with the original. Anyway, it sounds like you gotten a hold of some sort of customized version.

Comment: @martineau I'm thinking my custom installation of d3dshot somehow installed a custom version of Pillow. I'll try uninstalling and reinstalling all that stuff and see if it helps. Thanks

Comment: I've encountered this same issue with a previously working install of Pytorch... but my conda environment hadn't been updated since August last year. The thing that finally fixed it was re-installing the entire virtual environment - reinstalling just the package didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several references suggest capitalizing `Pillow` when installing it via pip, including [the official documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/), and a lot of related stack overflow posts [e.g. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505958/why-cant-python-import-image-from-pil/53069135).

I'd suggest trying `Pillow = ">=7.1.2"` with a capital P in the pyproject.toml.

For anyone else with this issue, uninstalling `pillow` and ensuring it is installed using `Pillow` might resolve the issue.